# AJAX not updating data on server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database

I'm developing something like a guestbook where people can leave a comment which I want to save at my db.

My js:

```
function sendContentToFile(id, name){
    var idB, nameB, d, tag, stunden, minuten, month, monat,datum, content;
    d = new Date();
    tag = d.getDate();
    stunden = d.getHours();
    minuten = d.getMinutes();
    month = new Array();
    month[0] = "Januar";
    month[1] = "Februar";
    month[2] = "März";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "Mai";
    month[5] = "Juni";
    month[6] = "Juli";
    month[7] = "August";
    month[8] = "September";
    month[9] = "Oktober";
    month[10] = "November";
    month[11] = "Dezember";
    monat = month[d.getMonth()];
    if(minuten <= 9) minuten = 0+ d.getMinutes();
    datum = tag + ". " + monat + " , "+ stunden + ":" + minuten;
    idB = id;
    nameB = name;
    content = document.getElementById("textarea"+nameB+'0'+idB).value;

   var url = 'comments.php';
   var neuesObject = {"Name" : nameB, "id" : idB, "comment" : content,"datum" : datum  };
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

   http.open('POST', url);
   http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", neuesObject.length);
   http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

   http.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {  
    }
  }
        var jsonObject = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
        obj.push(neuesObject); 
        jsonObject = JSON.stringify(obj);
        http.send(jsonObject);
}
```

My comments.php:

```
 [ { "Name" : "OS", "id" : "1", "comment" : "Hier steht das geladene kommentar drin" , "datum" : "11:32, 12. Feb" }]
```

after using the code the php file didn't get updated...
Can someone help me?

Comment: `var jsonObject = xmlhttp.responseText;` makes zero sense.

Comment: you mean  that the db does not get updated?

Comment: yeah  - my  comments.php didnt update

Comment: @epascarello is right... And, comments.php will never be updated... it will be simply requested to the server and, if the server understands php, it will be run; but **not** updated... it should contain some logic to update what you need to update...